# Glide rounded corner on notifydatasetchanged() is lost and becoming square

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm loading image url using glide and applying rounded corner transformation. It works fine for first setup of recyclerview. Later when i call `notifydatasetchanged()` after pagination it becomes square. What am I missing?

```
Glide.with(mContext)
      .load(primary.getpSmallImage())
      .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(mContext, 8, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL))
      .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ph_small)
      .into(thumbnailImage);
```

Comment: You're referencing `thumbnailImage` directly? You would expect to see `holder.thumbnailImage` instead.

Comment: Hi. this code is written inside viewholder.

Answer (score 2):

Use this diskCacheStrategy Saves the media item after all transformations to cache.

```
  Glide.with(mContext)
  .load(primary.getpSmallImage())
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
  .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(mContext, 8, 0, 
   RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL))
  .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ph_small)
  .into(thumbnailImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem happens after calling `notifydatasetchanged()` then don't use it. In fact, that method takes a lot of CPU resources and recreate every item in recyclerview even these items have been already added.

When paginating use `notifyItemInserted` or `notifyItemRangeInserted`. It'll allow you to avoid your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method for pagination at all. instead use `notifyItemInserted()`. [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) is a better choice for your apps performance.

If you're loading your image inside `onBindViewHolder()` method this problem shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
datalist.clear(); //clear old data before adddi
SampleAdapter adapter = (SampleAdapter) recyclerview.getAdapter();
recyclerview.setAdapter(null);
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
datalist.addAll(resource.getData());//add new data
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I also had the same problem and fixed it in this way